# Why does this search.php not work?

Tags: search, conditional-tags, template-tags

This search.php shows all the results from a said search however, doesn't include the title, The Search Results For...... and search query amount; or even the no searches found and prints the searchform.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

 <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'nothing' ), '' . get_search_query() . '' ); ?></h1>


<!--custom area--> 

<ul id="post-list">

 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


<?php
 $featured = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_thumbnail_id',true);
 $attachments = get_children( 'post_type=attachment&orderby=menu_order&exclude='.$featured.'&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='.$post->ID );
 $vimeo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_post-vimeo',true);?>
<li class="post">

<span class="entry-published">
<time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d')?>"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
    <!--Start Single Image-->
<?php  get_template_part( 'includes/inc-image' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<!--End Single Image-->


<!--Start Rest Of Post Content-->
<?php  get_template_part( 'includes/inc-detail' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>


<section id="pagination">
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?> 
</section>

<!--End Rest Of Post Content-->

</li>

</ul>


<!-- end of custom area -->



<?php else : ?>
<h2><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'nothing' ); ?></h2>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'twentyten' ); ?></p>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Interesting though the posts in their li tag appear witin the opening

```
<h1 class="page-title">
```

So i assume its a statement issue but cannot figure it out :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two potential issues:

1. You have `if ( have_posts() ) :` twice.

Here:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'nothing' ), '' . get_search_query() . '' ); ?></h1>
```

And here:

```
<ul id="post-list">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

1. The [`get_template_part()` template tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) expects a filename **slug**, rather than a **path**. So you may want to use the [`locate_template()` template tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) instead for these:

Try:

```
<?php  locate_template( 'includes/inc-image.php' ); ?>
<?php  locate_template( 'includes/inc-detail.php' ); ?>
```

**EDIT**

> The locate_template doesn't load any content when i apply that...

Do those files *exist*?

> ...and removing one of the if gives me an unexpected T_ELSEIF error... :(

Yeah, because you have an improperly opened/closed `else/if` construct. Get rid of the stray `endif` here:

```
<?php  get_template_part( 'includes/inc-image' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT 2**

So, here's a rewrite, attempted to fix your syntax errors:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'nothing' ), '' . get_search_query() . '' ); ?></h1>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <ul id="post-list">

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
            $featured = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_thumbnail_id',true);
            $attachments = get_children( 'post_type=attachment&orderby=menu_order&exclude='.$featured.'&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='.$post->ID );
            $vimeo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_post-vimeo',true);
            ?>
            <li class="post">

                <span class="entry-published">
                <time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d')?>"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
                <!--Start Single Image-->
                <?php  get_template_part( 'includes/inc-image' ); ?>
                <!--End Single Image-->

                <!--Start Rest Of Post Content-->
                <?php  get_template_part( 'includes/inc-detail' ); ?>

                <!--End Rest Of Post Content-->

            </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

    <section id="pagination">
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?> 
    </section>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'nothing' ); ?></h2>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'twentyten' ); ?></p>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Verify that works, and then we'll tackle the template-part output issues.

Comment: The locate_template doesn't load any content when i apply that and removing one of the if gives me an unexpected T_ELSEIF error... :(

Comment: See updated answer, addressing these two issues.

Comment: Thanks chip.

Yes the files exist because the page content is loading originally and does on the index.php also. Its the search.php elements title etc that is not.

Still get another unexpected T_ELSE error... :(

Comment: "*Still get another unexpected T_ELSE error... :(*" - yes, because there are more such errors. I would suggest cleaning up your PHP syntax, and **then** attempting to figure out what's going on with your query output.

Comment: The page works perfectly on index.php and in single.php, its only once it tries to display the search results in search.php does it play up...

Comment: See edit #2 to the question, that attempts to fix your syntax errors.